# Set a default on my dictonary python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Question I only want to grab my view_id column from my data base however I would like some sequential number for my first key. Below is what I have so far any help would be greatly appreciated!

This gives me a syntax error if I try to set count as the first key:

```
import pyodbc

class ShopView(object):

  def getViews(self):
    conn = pyodbc.connect(r'DSN=mydb;UID=test;PWD=xxxxxxxxxxxxx')
    sql = "SELECT DISTINCT view_id FROM [TEST].[dbo].[SHOP_VIEW]"
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql)
    count = 0
    try:
      return {'shop_views':
              [dict(zip(count += 1, [column[0] for column in cursor.description], row))
               for row in cursor.fetchall()]}
    finally:
      cursor.close()
      conn.close()
```

I also tried this, but I get a new error: `ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is required`

```
try:
  return {'shop_views':
          [dict(zip([data[0] for data in str(cursor.rowcount)], [column[0] for column in cursor.description], row))
           for row in cursor.fetchall()]}
finally:
  cursor.close()
  conn.close()
```

Here is what it looks like now

```
{'shop_views': [{'view_id': 'ACTOB'}, {'view_id': 'BANDDIES'}, {'view_id': 'SpareNCLathe'}]}
```

Here is what I would like it to look like:

```
{'shop_views': [{'count': '1', 'view_id': 'ACTOB'}{'count': '2', 'view_id': 'BANDDIES'}, {'count': '3', 'view_id': 'SpareNCLathe'}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested (well not with your db and connector) but this:

```
[dict(count=str(index), view_id=row[0]) for index, row in enumerate(cursor, 1)]
```

should match your expected result.

from the doc:

```
class enumerate(object)
 |  enumerate(iterable[, start]) -> iterator for index, value of iterable
 |  
 |  Return an enumerate object.  iterable must be another object that supports
 |  iteration.  The enumerate object yields pairs containing a count (from
 |  start, which defaults to zero) and a value yielded by the iterable argument.
 |  enumerate is useful for obtaining an indexed list:
 |      (0, seq[0]), (1, seq[1]), (2, seq[2]), ...
```

Note that I'm passing the `cursor` directly, in most db-api implementations the cursor is itself an iterable - a lazy one so you can avoid loading the whole resultset in memory (which is what happens with `.fetchall()`) when you just want to iterate over it. If you get a `TypeError: XXX object is not iterable` exception then pass `cursor.fetchall()` instead of `cursor` (and contact the pyodbc maintainers to ask them to make `cursor` iterable).

Comment: Awesome you are correct thank you so much! @bruno desthuilliers

Comment: Thanks for the explanation as well, I will defiantly keep that in mind.